# Image Gallery keeps causing page to jump

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a CCS and HTML only image gallery slider.

I've got the slider working, however whenever a button is press, the focus jumps down on the page.

I've tried everything i can think of but no success :(

Any help would be great!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
</div> <!-- end of header -->

<nav>
<ul>

<a href="index.html"><li id="HomeButton"><img id="HomeText" src="Images/Icons/HomeText.png" />
</li></a>

<a href="whatswhat.html"><li id="WhatsWhatButton">
<img id="WhatsWhatText" src="Images/Icons/WhatsWhatText.png" />
</li></a>

<a href="FoodFromPlants.html"><li id="FoodFromPlantsButton">
<img id="FoodFromPlantsText" src="Images/Icons/FoodFromPlantsText.png" />
</li></a>

<a href="howplantsgrow.html"><li id="HowPlantsGrowButton">
<div id="HowPlantsGrowText"><img src="Images/Icons/HowPlantsGrowText.png" />
</div>
<div id="HowPlantsGrowIcon"></div>
</li></a>

<a href="plantGame.html"><li id="PlantGameButton">
<img id="PlantGameText" src="Images/Icons/PlantGameText.png" />
</li></a>
</ul>

<form>
 <select accesskey="S" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
<option value="index.html">Home</option>
<option value="whatswhat.html">Whats What</option>
<option value="FoodFromPlants.html">Food From Plants</option>
<option value="howplantsgrow.html">How Plants Grow</option>
</select>
</form>

</nav> <!-- end of nav -->

<div id="page">
<div id="content">

<img class="title" src="Images/Icons/FoodFromPlantsTitle.png" width="250" height="100"/>

<div id="images">
    <img id="image1" src="Images/ImageGallery/Bananas.jpg" />
    <img id="image2" src="Images/ImageGallery/Apples.jpg" />
    <img id="image3" src="Images/ImageGallery/Broccoli.jpg" />
    <img id="image4" src="Images/ImageGallery/Carrots.jpg" />
    <img id="image5" src="Images/ImageGallery/Onions.jpg" />
    <img id="image6" src="Images/ImageGallery/Peas.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="slider">
    <a href="#image1">1</a>
    <a href="#image2">2</a>
    <a href="#image3">3</a>
    <a href="#image4">4</a>
    <a href="#image5">5</a>
    <a href="#image6">6</a>

</div>
</div> <!-- end of content -->
</div> <!-- end of page -->

<footer>
</footer> <!-- end of footer -->
</div>  <!-- end of container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#images {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#images img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -400px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all linear 500ms;
    -o-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 500ms;
}
#images img:target {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    opacity: 1;
}
#images img:first-child {
    left: 0;
}
#slider a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #E3F1FA;
    border: 1px solid #C6E4F2;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    color: #222;
}
#slider a:hover {
    background: #C6E4F2;
}
```

Comment: What's in `SlideShow.js`? See if you can get a demo working at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: the <a href="#imageN"> and thier counterparts <img id="imageN"> is an anchor, and if you click the hyperlink  the page will usually focus on the related anchor if clicked on..  would need to see the javascript to see if this can be mitigated

Comment: the focus jumps down on the page. ? how? can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Apologies, SlideShow.js was something i used while trying another method, it isn't used, have updated code with its removal.

For an example of how the page jumps:

http://www.mattmeadows.info/MFTW234/FoodFromPlants.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can fix your current method without adding JavaScript.

With jQuery it would be really simple to fade your images in and out on click.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/sVmTn/) for a live example.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".selector").click(function () {  
$('#image1').fadeToggle(); 
});
</script>
```

Just replace ".selector" with the class or id of the element you want to use as your trigger.

Comment: Would a library be required to linked into that?

Comment: @MattMeadows yes a library would be needed, see updated answer.

Comment: @MattMeadows for even more cheap thrills you can add timing and easing - http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/sVmTn/2/